# Regex to match start of line and end of line for quick find and replace

Tags: regex, ide, replace, myeclipse

Hey guys I've got a whole lot of HTML to format with

```
myString + "<somehtml></somehtml>";
```

Need 2 regex things, one to replace all new lines with `myString + "`
and one to replace all end of lines with `";`

Just using MyEclipse, Find and replace with regex enabled. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual regular expression engines may vary, but generally speaking, '^' will match the beginning of a line and '$' will match the end of a line.

Comment: Need to put it in [^] thats throwing an error, sigh I dunno if this is possible?

Comment: I've never used that particular flavor of Eclipse, but on vanilla eclipse, if you just search for '(^)' and replace with 'myString + "' (both without the outer single quotes when actually typing it in), you should get the desired effect. Also, [this](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/09/some-useful-regular-expressions-for.html) link shows how to access regex help for Eclipse.