# Eclipse Regex Search for beginning and end of line not working

Tags: regex, eclipse

This is a small question, but it has been nagging me for a while.  When I do a **Find** or **Find/Replace** in Eclipse and I use `^` or `$` and check the **Regular Expressions** box, I always get a message:

`String Not Found`

I don't understand why.  I know about the `CTRL+SPACE` content assist feature and even when I select `^` from the list, it does not work.

I was looking at this question, [Regex to match start of line and end of line for quick find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003908/regex-to-match-start-of-line-and-end-of-line-for-quick-find-and-replace), but it is not working for me.  Other regex searches like `^.` or `;$` work fine.

I see that `^` and `$` are [anchor characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), and do not match a string per se, but these characters seem to work in other editors.

**EDIT:**

For example, I want to convert a list of data into an SQL in clause.

From:

```
1
2
3
Hi
I need to quote these!
```

To:

```
'1',
'2',
'3',
'Hi',
'I need to quote these!',
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` and `$` are zero-width anchors as you said, therefore they will not match anything by themselves.  You need to use something with the anchors in order to match anything in your file.

Comment: I'm wondering why this is. In other editors they do work by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it with this regex replace:

Find: `^(\s*)(.*)$`

Replace: `$1'$2',`

So what I do is use:

1. `^` to find the beginning of the line.
2. `(\s*)` to find and capture any white space.
3. `(.*)` to find and capture anything.
4. `$` to find the end of line.

Then replace with

- `$1` First capture
- `'` quote
- `$2` Second capture
- `',` quote comma

I wish `^` and `$` worked by themselves, but this is cool b/c I can do it in one operation.